# hovering over a button without triggering a change of the mouse pointer

Tags: html, css, pointers, mouse

I have a button on my site which activates a pop up contact form.
This button is constructed like this:

```
<a href="" class="button">Contact</a>
```

Though I want to remove the "a href" part, so that it can't be seen as a link. 

If I use the following:

```
<p class="button">Contact</p>
```

Then the a href is removed but the mouse changes into the following when hovering:
[image: mouse hover selection form]

Though I'd like it to stay in its normal form when hovering:
[image: mouse hover normal form]

Thought it would work with:

```
<img class="button">Contact</img>
```

But it doesn't. The mouse stays in its right form when hovering, but the word "Contact" is not visible with this example.

Anyone can think of a solution (without having to make an image for the button)?

Thanks in advance
Steven

Comment: If you're using a non-button element as a button, make sure to add the [`[role="button"]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#button).

Comment: `<img>` is a [void element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#void-elements) - it can't have any content. That's why `Contact` doesn't display when you do `<img class="button">Contact</img>`.

Comment: <p class="button1" style="cursor: default">Contact</p> worked. Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 5):

Add a CSS `cursor` property to your `<p>` tag or the respective class. ([MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor)):

```css
.button {
  /* your other styles */
  cursor: default
}
```

Comment: Nice, have been looking for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css :

```
.button{
   cursor: default;
}
```